# The Nice Classification, what exactly does it refer to?

Tags: copyright, trademark

I need to know if the [**Nice Classification**](https://www.wipo.int/classifications/nice/en/) (for trademark registration) determines the activities carried out by the brand itself, or if it refers to the areas in which the brand cannot be used by others.

For instance, if I want to use a logo from an old computer in a t-shirt design, and upon checking its classes, I see that none of them fall under Class 25 (related to clothing), but rather under computer and electronics classes, can I use that brand in my design for my retro computer tribute t-shirts?